# API call to calendar.events.insert failed with error: Invalid conference type value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, gsuite-addons

I am trying to build third party conferencing google calendar add-on.
For creating conference data, I am passing below object.

```
"conferenceData": {
        "createRequest": {
          "requestId": '7qxalsvy0e',
          "conferenceSolutionKey": {
            "type": 'addOn'
          }
        }
};
```

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.insert failed with error: Invalid conference type value.

Is something missing or wrong value is passed?

Comment: Hello @SonalShah, if you are **not** using a third party service, the `addOn` type is not available, you can check this [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events). So my question is, are you using a third party service for the conference? Cheers!

Comment: Yes. I am using third party service from conference. it will be very helpful if you can tell me steps how to add conference data for third party service

Comment: Hello @Sonal, can you confirm the service is configured correctly? Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13, how can I check the service is configured correctly !! what is the configuration steps?

Comment: Hello @SonalShah, which service are you using? Cheers!

Comment: I am not getting about which service you are asking.. I am using UrlFetch for authorize third party service.

Comment: Hello @SonalShah, thank you for the details provided, I understand at what you are referring to now. Do you have the same issue as described [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150402756)? Cheers!